# ios notification message delivery status

Tags: ios, push-notification

How to get the delivered status from APNS for push notifications when the application on iOS device is uninstalled?

Is there an online service to send a push notifications to ios devices and as a result get the status of delivered message in code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the functionality of the services like [Branch](https://branch.io/) and [Adjust](https://www.adjust.com/). They send silent push notifications and if it doesn't go to a device, they just mark that device as "uninstalled the app".

That's how they do uninstall tracking.